# What does app.engine() do ? And what are ext and callback?

Tags: node.js, express, web-development-server

I tried reading through the documentation and they said

> app.engine(ext, callback)
>
> Register the given template engine callback as ext By default will require() the engine based on the file extension. For example if you try to render a "foo.jade" file Express will invoke the following internally, and cache the require() on subsequent calls to increase performance.

I am having a tough time figuring out what do ext and callback here even mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of the *view/template engine* [functionality](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) of Express. Many times your request handlers only return some JSON object. But other times you want to build a regular "document" like a fully built HTML page, or RSS feed etc. Template engines help you achieve this, though they are by no means mandatory. You could use other approaches (build strings by hand for example, if you like the pain), or you could use a library such as pug/moustache etc by hand. The view engine functionality basically integrates libraries such as pug/moustache into express so it's easier to use them.

The linked page has a nice example of how this would be used in practice:

> Then create a route to render the index.pug file. If the view engine property is not set, you must specify the extension of the view file. Otherwise, you can omit it.
>
> `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
>     res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
>   })`
>
> When you make a request to the home page, the index.pug file will be rendered as HTML.

Many times express knows about various template engines. So it's enough to say `express.set('view engine', 'pug')` and it can do the right thing as long as the `pug` package is installed.

Other times you need to use `app.engine` to tell it more explicitly what to do. It is called like `app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express)`. The first parameter is just the extension express should be looking for. So when you say `req.render('index', ...)` it would look for an `index.jade` file. The second parameter is the function which actually does the integration between the view engine (which, as I've said, is a separate thing from express), and express itself. [`consolidate.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate) is a package with integrations for a lot of view engines.

But if you want to see what this function does, checkout [developing template engines for Express](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html). The `callback` parameter must look like `function(filePath, options, callback)`. `filePath` is just the name of the disk file to use for rendering, so `index.jade` in the example from above. `callback` is a standard node callback, invoked as `callback(err)` on error or `callback(null, renderedContent)` on success. `options` is an object passed in from the `req.render('index.jade', /* options */ { title: 'foo', content: 'bar' })`. It's then up to you to decide how to actually do the rendering based on the supplied arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms: ext - extension, callback - library (engine) that will render the file with the given extension.